# Creating custom validation for an ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I try to validate a textfield for IP addresses. But the logic is not in a controller. But just in a 'normal' class: `IpConditionSettings`. It is using serialize and deserialze for saving the data. But the validation is about the `IpAddress` in put field, like this:

```
<div class="form-group" id="hallo">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IpCondition.IpAddress, new { @class = "text-bold control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8 col-sm-10" id="hallo">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IpCondition.IpAddress, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control col-md-3" } })
        @*@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IpCondition.IpAddress, "", new { @class = "text-warning" })*@
    </div>
</div>
```

this is the propertie of `IpAddress`:

```
 [SfsHelpers.IpConditionRedirectValidation(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Entity.Product), ErrorMessageResourceName = "IpAddressWarning")]        
        [Display(Name = "PreConditionIpAddress", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Entity.Product))]       
        public string IpAddress { get; set; }
```

And this is the javascript:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        jQuery.validator.addMethod('mustflingsomething',
        function (value, element, params) {
            return false;
        }, '');

        jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add('mustflingsomething',
        function (options) {
            options.rules['mustflingsomething'] = {
            };
            options.messages['mustflingsomething'] = options.message;
        });
    }(jQuery));
</script>
```

And this is the validation class:

```
public class IpConditionRedirectValidation : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    public  IpConditionRedirectValidation() {}

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext) 
    {
         IpConditionSettings IpCondition = validationContext.ObjectInstance as IpConditionSettings ;

         if ((IpCondition.IpAddress.StartsWith("192") 
             || IpCondition.IpAddress.StartsWith("127")))
             return new ValidationResult("A monkey must fling something");

         if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(IpCondition.IpAddress))
             return new ValidationResult(this.FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));

         //return new ValidationResult("A monkey must fling something");
         return null;
    }

#region IClientValidatable Members

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        ModelClientValidationRule mvr = new ModelClientValidationRule();
        mvr.ErrorMessage = "Hey, you must fling something - you are a monkey after all";
        mvr.ValidationType = "mustflingsomething";

        return new[] { mvr };     
    }

#endregion
}
```

The serialize method looks like this:

```
internal string Serialize(EditProductModel model)
{
    XElement settings = XElement.Parse(model.Product.AuthenticationSettings ?? "<settings/>");
    XElement ipaddresses = new XElement("ipaddresses");

    if (IpAddress == null)
        return string.Empty;

    string[] lines = IpAddress.Split(
        new string[]  { Environment.NewLine },
         StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);               
    lines = IpAddress.Split(new char[0]);

    foreach (var item in lines)
    {
         if (item.StartsWith("127") || item.StartsWith("192"))
             //return  ("LogOnDetails", model);
             return model.Product.AuthenticationSettings;

          IPAddress address;// = null;
          if (IPAddress.TryParse(item, out address))
          {
               switch (address.AddressFamily)
               {
                   case System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork:
                       ipaddresses.Add(new XElement("ipaddress", item));
                       // we have IPv4
                   break;
                   case System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6:
                       // we have IPv6
                       ipaddresses.Add(new XElement("ipaddress", item));
                   break;
                   default:
                   break;
              }
          }  
      }
      settings.Add(ipaddresses);
      return settings.ToString();
}
```

So first I want to check if the `Ipaddress` begins with: 127 or 192. If it begins with that numbers you cant save the data. Otherwise you can save the data.

But the problem is now. That for every number you put in the `Ipaddress` field is false. So you cant save any number

Thank you

Comment: Somebody any ideer? Thank you

Comment: You need to debug your validation attribute and find what is wrong then ask the issue. Your question can not be answered without debugging.